# How do i pass a prop from a parent as context to its child?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

so i am fetching a data in react, and i want to pass an individual value from the response in a context from a parent as prop, trendingData is from a response in api call. code:

```
  if (loading) return <Loading />;
  return (
    <VidoesContainer>
      <TopBar />
      <FitnessChallenge />
      <MainContainer>
        <Category categoryData={trendingData} />
        <Trainers />
      </MainContainer>
    </VidoesContainer>
  );
```

the initial value of trendingData is undefined, trendingData is passed to a screen stacks in react navigation. I want to use it in context like this:

```
const CategoryScreenStack = ({ categoryData }) => {
  return (
    <CategoryContext.Provider value={categoryData}>
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName='Category'>
        <Stack.Screen name='Category' component={Category} />
        <Stack.Screen
          name='Video'
          options={{
            transitionSpec: {
              open: TransitionSpecs.FadeInFromBottomAndroidSpec,
              close: TransitionSpecs.FadeOutToBottomAndroidSpec,
            },
          }}
          component={Video}
        />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </CategoryContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

but i get an error: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_useContext.name') when i only just want to avoid prop drilling on each screens. How do i pass a prop from a parent as context to its child?

Answer (score 0):

**[Edit]** After reading again your question, this doesn't answer it, and it's pretty dumb since you are probably already using hooks in your children component.
Now, it looks like you are trying to access a property `name` of undefined so make sure your data are available in your context. Here ishow i would handle this:

```
export const App = () => {
  const [trendingData, setTrendingData] = useSate(undefined);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('...').then((response) => {
      setTrendingData(response.someData);
    });
  });

  const loading = trendingData === undefined;

  if (loading) return <Loading />;
  return (
    <VidoesContainer>
      <TopBar />
      <FitnessChallenge />
      <MainContainer>
        <Category categoryData={trendingData} />
        <Trainers />
      </MainContainer>
    </VidoesContainer>
  );
};
```

The idea is to add trendingData in your condition to render or not your component. Here i represent it by just a simple condition, you will have to adapt it to your own way. Same thing goes for the effect, I did a fetch inside but just adapt it or provide more code so i can be more precise.

Hope it helps :)

---

I think you need to dispatch your trendingData after you API call. This way you will be able to use it as a normal context value. You could make use of the useContext():

`[state, dispatch] = useContext(CategoryContext);`

This way you will have access to your state. It can be done in every stateless component where you need to use the state or dispatch new data to it. Of course you will need a reducer.

If you don't know what I'm talking about, I highly recommand you to take a look at [The official documentation aboutHooks](https://fr.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html)